# Problem with deleting data from database using ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax

I am working on a cms for properties/ads in oop php for learning purposes. I am trying to delete photos from database using ajax and php. I am having trouble when I click on X button on photo in my view it removes it, but when I refresh page it pops back up again, and also it doesn't remove it from database. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

index.php:

```
<?php foreach ($data1 as $key => $value) : ?>

    <?php if($key == 1) { ?>
    <div class="img-wrap">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img src="<?php echo '/public/photos/'.$value->name.'.'.$value->extension ?>" data-id="<?php echo $value->name ?>" width="150" height="150">
    </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <div class="img-wrap">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img src="<?php echo '/public/photos/'.$value->name.'.'.$value->extension ?>" data-id="<?php echo $value->name ?>" width="150" height="150">
                     </div>
                 <?php } ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>


<script>
$('.img-wrap .close').on('click', function() {
    var that = this;
    var id = $(that).closest('.img-wrap').find('img').data('id');
    var confirmation = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this picture?");

    if (confirmation) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ads/deletephoto',
            //dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify( { "name": id } ),
            processData: false,
            success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ) {
              console.log( $(that).closest('.img-wrap') );
                $(that).closest('.img-wrap').hide();
            },
            error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                console.log( errorThrown );
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

AdModel:

```
public function deletePropertyPhoto($id)
{
  $this->db->query('DELETE FROM photos WHERE id=(SELECT photo_id FROM property_photo WHERE property_id=:property_id)');
  $this->db->bind(':property_id', $id);
  $this->db->execute();
  $this->db->query('DELETE FROM property_photo WHERE property_id=:property_id');
  $this->db->bind(':property_id', $id);
  $this->db->execute();
}
```

AdsController:

```
public function deletePhotoAction()
 {
    $userinfo = $this->Auth->Auth(['admin', 'moderator']);
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $_GET = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $this->Auth->isSet($_GET['id'], "ads/index");

            $photo = $this->AdModel->deletePropertyPhoto($_GET['id']);
            if ($photo != false) {
              if (file_exists('public/photos/' . $photo->photo)) {
                unlink('public/photos/' . $photo->photo);
              }
            }
            redirect('ads/index');

          echo "Property is not found!!!";
     } 
 }
```

Comment: What debugging have you done so far? Have you checked the console for errors? Checked the network tab in the browsers dev-tools to see exactly what is posted and what the response you get when making your request using ajax? Have you checked the servers error log?

Comment: In your ajax code, change: `data: JSON.stringify( { "name": id } ),` to `data: { "name": id },` (removing the json.strinigfy()). jQuery will handle the serialization for you.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I checked console for errors and there are none and also servers log and same there.

Comment: Have you tried removing json.stringify() and just passing the js-object directly instead, like I wrote in the second comment?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb you should never fully `DELETE` rows from a table. Other methods, like marking the row as deleted, or removing the content are more wise long term solutions for data storage.

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing the correct id to the query? `id` vs. `property_id`?

Comment: @odan this is query for that    public function deletePropertyPhoto($id)
    {
      $this->db->query('DELETE FROM photos WHERE id=(SELECT photo_id FROM property_photo WHERE property_id=:property_id)');
      $this->db->bind(':property_id', $id);
      $this->db->execute();
      $this->db->query('DELETE FROM property_photo WHERE property_id=:property_id');
      $this->db->bind(':property_id', $id);
      $this->db->execute();
    }

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I removed  json.stringify() it still does the same. And in network tab when I click deletephoto and response it says failed to load response data also now in console I get this  jQuery.fn.init [div.img-wrap, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
0: div.img-wrap
length: 1
prevObject: jQuery.fn.init [span.close]
__proto__: Object(0)